# Como inserir um item antes e fora de um outro item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como inserir um item via Jquery de forma que ele fique ANTES e FORA de um outro item em específico(aceito edições para melhorar a forma de perguntar).

O exemplo a seguir insere antes, porém dentro do item `add-mesa-de-luz-button`.

```js
$("#add-mesa-de-luz-button").click(function () {
        $("#add-mesa-de-luz-button").prepend(
          "<tr><td>Item adicionado</td></tr>"
        ); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="add-mesa-de-luz-button">
    <td>Botão de adicionar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

O resultado do HTML fica assim:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="add-mesa-de-luz-button">
        <tr><td>Item adicionado</td></tr>
        <td>Botão de adicionar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Porém gostaria que fosse inserido antes e fora do item `add-mesa-de-luz-button`, de forma que fique assim:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Item adicionado</td></tr>
    <tr id="add-mesa-de-luz-button">
        <td>Botão de adicionar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Utilize `before` ao invés do `prepand`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O *jQuery* possui alguns métodos para adicionar o conteúdo antes de determinado elementos, dois deles são: `.prepend()` e `.before()`.

---

#### *Prepend*

Neste método o *jQuery* irá capturar o elemento `#add-mesa-de-luz-button` e irá adicionar o conteúdo antes do primeiro elemento. Esta função é a oposta à `.append()`

```js
$("ul").prepend("<li>Um</li>")
$("ul").append("<li>Cinto</li>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Dois</li>
  <li>Três</li>
  <li>Quadro</li>
</ul>
```

#### *Before*

Neste método o *jQuery* irá capturar o elemento `#add-mesa-de-luz-button` e irá adicionar o conteúdo antes dele. Esta função é a oposta à `.after()`

```js
$("ul").before("Before")
$("ul").after("After")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Dois</li>
  <li>Três</li>
  <li>Quadro</li>
</ul>
```